# AttributeError: 'Session' object has no attribute 'save'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use SQLAlchemy, but in the line:

```
session.save(login)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Session' object has no attribute 'save'
```

This is my code:

```
def findOrCreateLogin(self, username, password):
    login = self.findLogin(username)
    if login:
        return login
    else:
        login = DBLogin(username,password)
        session.save(login)
        return login
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no `.save()` method for an SQLAlchemy session. You can add things to an SQLAlchemy session by:

```
session.add(login) # Adds a thing to the session.
session.commit() # Commits this session to the database (saves the data).
```

More information [in the session docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session.html)

Your code should look like this:

```
def findOrCreateLogin(self, username, password):
    login = self.findLogin(username)
    if login:
        return login
    else:
        login = DBLogin(username,password)
        session.add(login)
        session.commit()
        return login
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, `session.save` used to exists in older version of SQLAlchemy.

So if others are looking for a new way of doing `insert or update` kind of feature - you should use `merge`:

```
# if the keys ( primary etc .. ) matching an existing row - it will be updated
# if not - it will be "inserted" as new

new_obj = session.merge(obj)
session.commit()
```

vs

```
def findOrCreateLogin() ...
```